# Aligning column content with Bootstrap 4

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to align some rows and columns using bootstrap to make my html display something like this....

[image]

I tried using code like this...

```
<div class="container"> 
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-2"><span><strong>Data</strong></span></div>
  <div class="col-sm-1">Information</div>

  <div class="col-sm-2 offset-sm-12"><strong>Date due</strong></div>
  <div class="col-sm-1 offset-sm-12">11/28/2017</div>      
</div>
```

But i'm having trouble getting the alignment right. Can someone help me with getting the first row right with somewhat similar alignment to the image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can **align the text** in the columns with `text-right`. Using `offset` will move the columns, but not align the content in the columns.

https://www.codeply.com/go/vxOqKdz0D4

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-3 text-right"><span><strong>Data</strong></span></div>
        <div class="col-sm-2">Information</div>
        <div class="col-sm-3 text-right"><strong>Date due</strong></div>
        <div class="col-sm-2">11/28/2017</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Read the [Bootstrap text alignment docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/utilities/text/#text-alignment)

Answer (score 0):

You used the `offset-*` class wrong way. It should not be `offset-*-12`. Try this code.

```
<div class="container"> 
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-2 text-right"><strong>Data</strong></div>
        <div class="col-sm-2">Information</div>

        <div class="col-sm-2 offset-sm-4 text-right"><strong>Date due</strong></div>
        <div class="col-sm-2 offset-sm-4">11/28/2017</div>
    </div>
</div>
```